# react js and node Can't see img of new user

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

When I try to register a new user all data are passed except "avatar", even if that avatar is regularly uploaded on my Cloudinary.

Don't even know what is the problem in and tried to find answer on google but unsuccessfully, so any help is very welcome :D

Here is some code, if need more tell me in a comment and I'll send you

Cannot finish my site, don't know what to do...

```
// frontend Register component
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import MetaData from '../layout/MetaData';

import { useAlert } from 'react-alert';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { register, clearErrors } from '../../actions/userActions';

const Register = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
  });

  const { name, email, password } = user;

  const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState('');
  const [avatarPreview, setAvatarPreview] = useState(
    '/images/default_avatar.jpg'
  );

  const alert = useAlert();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { isAuthenticated, error, loading } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.auth
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      navigate('/');
    }

    if (error) {
      alert.error(error);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }
  }, [dispatch, alert, isAuthenticated, error, navigate]);

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.set('name', name);
    formData.set('email', email);
    formData.set('password', password);
    formData.set('avatar', avatar);

    dispatch(register(formData));
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name === 'avatar') {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = () => {
        if (reader.readyState === 2) {
          setAvatarPreview(reader.result);
          setAvatar(reader.result);
        }
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    } else {
      setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <MetaData title={'Register User'} />

      <div className='row wrapper'>
        <div className='col-10 col-lg-5'>
          <form
            className='shadow-lg'
            onSubmit={submitHandler}
            encType='multipart/form-data'
          >
            <h1 className='mb-3'>Register</h1>

            <div className='form-group'>
              <label htmlFor='email_field'>Name</label>
              <input
                type='name'
                id='name_field'
                className='form-control'
                name='name'
                value={name}
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            </div>

            <div className='form-group'>
              <label htmlFor='email_field'>Email</label>
              <input
                type='email'
                id='email_field'
                className='form-control'
                name='email'
                value={email}
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            </div>

            <div className='form-group'>
              <label htmlFor='password_field'>Password</label>
              <input
                type='password'
                id='password_field'
                className='form-control'
                name='password'
                value={password}
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            </div>

            <div className='form-group'>
              <label htmlFor='avatar_upload'>Avatar</label>
              <div className='d-flex align-items-center'>
                <div>
                  <figure className='avatar mr-3 item-rtl'>
                    <img
                      src={avatarPreview}
                      className='rounded-circle'
                      alt='Avatar Preview'
                    />
                  </figure>
                </div>
                <div className='custom-file'>
                  <input
                    type='file'
                    name='avatar'
                    className='custom-file-input'
                    id='customFile'
                    accept='iamges/*'
                    onChange={onChange}
                  />
                  <label className='custom-file-label' htmlFor='customFile'>
                    Choose Avatar
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <button
              id='register_button'
              type='submit'
              className='btn btn-block py-3'
              disabled={loading ? true : false}
            >
              REGISTER
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

```
// backend  Register a user => /api/v1/register
exports.registerUser = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  const result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.body.avatar, {
    folder: 'avatars',
    width: 150,
    crop: 'scale',
  });

  const { name, email, password } = req.body;

  const user = await User.create({
    name,
    email,
    password,
    avatar: {
      public_id: result.public_id,
      url: result.secure_url,
    },
  });

  sendToken(user, 200, res);
});
```

Comment: Did you try to log the `req.body.avatar`?

Comment: Yes, in log i see that it is img but when i register new user img are not in state

Comment: Are you trying to set the response link as the image source? I'm not following. Is the "setAvatar" in the client doesn't work?